# Php regex duplicate replace the end of string ($)

Tags: php, regex

I have the code below to add at the end of source string the string "QWE":

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('/$/','QWE',"<p>123</p>    
<p>456</p>\r\n"
)
?>
```

The result is:

```
# php p.php
<p>123</p>    
QWE456</p>
QWE
```

The result must be like below:

```
# php p.php
<p>123</p>    
456</p>
QWE
```

May be something wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thanks all for suggestions.

After some tests I've found the temporary solution. If I replace the double quotes to single quotes the result is ok.

But I couldn't understand why the double quotes string behaves so strange.

Comment: Is multiline the default state of php regex ? And is preg_replace default a global replace? If the answer is no to both, then it should have added only QWE at the end of the string.

Comment: You know something is wrong because if Multiline and Global mode were in affect, the result would be this string `"<p>123</p>   QWE\n<p>456</p>QWE\nQWE"` not the result you show.

Comment: @sln [multiline is *not* the default](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). `preg_replace` *is* global, though. I'm not able to reproduce the OP's results though, but I am receiving strange results (`QWE` on the last two lines). After some testing, it looks like there are two replacements made (`\r\n\r\n` still results in only two `QWE`s). ([Try it here.](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)). Strange, strange indeed.

Comment: @bfrohs - The results looked strange is all. Yeah, I'm not suprised it is replaced twice, but the replacements are separated by a newline. Thats because as Perl/PCRE docs say, in default mode (single line) `$` will match before the _last_ newline, or end of string (in that order too) if it can. So if there exists a newline at the end, globally it will match in two positions, before and after the newline.

Comment: The ideal solution is to concatenate QWE to the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$` use `\z` for end of input in multiline input data:

```
echo preg_replace('/\z/','QWE','<p>123</p>

<p>456</p>'."\r\n"
);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
<p>123</p>

<p>456</p>
QWE
```